# Jquery EasyUI- How to get checkbox checked or not checked in easyui-datagrid table td

Tags: jquery-easyui

i am new to jeasyui. I generated dynamic table with easyui-datagrid and have to enable checkbox for each row. Now i want get each row details when checked and uncheck on checkbox for particular row.

```
<table id="process-list" title="Video Processing" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:700px;height:250px"
        url="$/emplyoee/getfiles.action"
        idField="itemid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
     <th field='ck' checkbox="true"  type="checkbox" ></th> 
             <th field="id" width="50" >Id</th>              
            <th  field="createDate" width="50" >CreateDate</th>
            <th field="product" width="50">Product</th>             
            <th field="no.Files" width="50">No.Files</th>
            <th field="status" width="50">Status</th>
            <th field="cycle" width="50">Cycle</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

$(document).ready(function() { 
$('input[name="ck"]').click(function(){
if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
    alert("Checkbox is checked.");
}
else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
    alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
}  

});
```

I tried with click function but it's not working.
    });

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What have you tried so far? Please note that Stackoverflow isn't a coding service. We expect you to have done your research and at least come up with some attempts, in which you got stuck somewhere and have a specific question with that in mind. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Martin:Check my updated question.

Comment: I don't see any input, or any element at all actually, with the name property *name="ck"* attached to any of your elements.

Comment: AS @Martin has mentioned, where is your input field for the checkbox? Right now you are using the <th> as a substitute for your <input>. The .prop("checked") is not doing anything in this cas as you do not check the <th>

Comment: @radu apostolescu: it's generated dynamic table with tbody,tr,td inside input tag will generate.

Comment: @mravu can you try targeting the input directly then? Instead of going for the <th>?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('table').on('click','td input',function(){
if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
    alert("Checkbox is checked.");
}
else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
    alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
}  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this is jquery table. I want datagrid table on easyui

Comment: try replacing jQuery table with datagrid table on easyui. It works.

Comment: not possible... in my application we are using easyui.. in jquery i know. But i want easyui